# Load PDF in CefSharp without typical refresh

Tags: pdf, browser, cefsharp

I have a winforms application in which the working is, I click on a file name and it is loaded
as a PDF in CefSharp, for each file click, I convert the file to PDF and then load that PDF
in CefSharp, this gives a bad eye impact as every time the PDF is loaded, it typically refreshes
the page.
Sample screen recording [is here](https://vimeo.com/705298666/6d3242711e)

Can I replace that effect with some smooth transition like we have in power point ?
Basically looking for a minimal smooth effect so that time is not wasted on the effect, and the
basic need of eye-impact is also achieved.

Any help may be appreciated as this application is being used by teachers to go through
multiple word files quickly.

Comment: There's no built in option, so you'll have to get creative. You can use multiple ChromiumWebBrowser instances, potentially creating one in the background and transitioning between them. If you were using WPF you could potentially ignore some frames. Time to out your thinking hat on.

Comment: Thats a nice suggestion, I too had a feeling that I might need a hack here. Thanks